# How do i make it so that the chat autmatically updates when the user send a message?

Tags: javascript, chat

I am trying to make a chat, that functions noramlly. As you can see here, i have some code that should output some text from a bot, then you can type into a textbox then press the "send" button to send text and it should automatically show up in the chat. I don't know why it is not appearing!

Please help thank you:)

Javascript:

```
let chatMsg = ["Hello! Welcome to this game. Please press 'i' for instructions!"];

let Game = {
  currentGame:{
    variables:{
      sendMessage:function(messageContent) {
        chatMsg.push(messageContent)
      }
    }
  }
}

let username = "CommunityBot";


for (let i = 0; i < chatMsg.length; i++) {
  
  let chatElem = document.createElement("p");

  chatElem.innerHTML = "<strong>"+username+": </strong>"+chatMsg[i];
  
  document.querySelector(".chat").appendChild(chatElem);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="chat">
          <h1>
            CHAT

          </h1>

        </div>
        <div>
          <input class="enterT" type="text" placeholder="Enter A Message..!"><button onclick="Game.currentGame.variables.sendMessage(document.querySelector('.enterT').innerHTML)">send message</button>
        </div>
```

Kevin

Comment: `.value` should be used instead of `.innerHTML` to get input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 small problems with your code.

Firstly, your input value should be accessed by `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`

```
document.querySelector('.enterT').innerHTML
```

To

```
document.querySelector('.enterT').value
```

Secondly, you only call `chatMsg.push(messageContent)` but don't update `document` after you update input value.

```js
let chatMsg = ["Hello! Welcome to this game. Please press 'i' for instructions!"];

//the function to support adding message to the document
function appendChatMessage(currentUserName, chatMessage) {
  let chatElem = document.createElement("p");
  chatElem.innerHTML = "<strong>" + currentUserName + ": </strong>" + chatMessage;
  document.querySelector(".chat").appendChild(chatElem);
}

let username = "CommunityBot";
for (let i = 0; i < chatMsg.length; i++) {
  appendChatMessage(username, chatMsg[i])
}

let Game = {
  currentGame: {
    variables: {
      sendMessage: function(messageContent) {
        chatMsg.push(messageContent);
        //update your message in the document
        appendChatMessage(username, messageContent);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
  <h1>
    CHAT
  </h1>
</div>
<div>
  <input class="enterT" type="text" placeholder="Enter A Message..!"><button onclick="Game.currentGame.variables.sendMessage(document.querySelector('.enterT').value)">send message</button>
</div>
```